# React - Material UI - Expanded accordion ignores parent div max height

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have Accordions inside this div:

```
.deviationContent {
    max-height: calc(100% - 365px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The problem is with expanding... After expansion, Accordion ignores max-height setting on the parent div. I need to have a header, content with scrollbar(accordions) and footer panel visible all the time.

Any advice on how to fix this issue?

Comment: I also want to know the answer to this